# After Fragment transaction, new Fragment's UI is transparent and makes the entire application unresponsive

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-lifecycle

There are Fragments A and B. The app starts with A and then, if some condition met, automatically navigates to B with slide animation:

```
fragmentTransaction
.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left)
.replace(R.id.container, mCurrentFragment, fragmentId)
.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

I know that keeping a reference to Fragments in `mCurrentFragment` is bad, but this reference isn't used for anything suspicious in this case.

Everything works alright in most cases.

However, if the application starts when some system dialog is shown (e.g. approve app's auto-start when connecting devices to USB using OTG), then something really strange happens: the app navigates to Fragment B, but it's UI is not shown and it remains transparent.

I reproduced the issue and even AndroidStudio's layout inspector claims that the currently visible UI belongs to Fragment B. When this happens, since Fragment B is transparent, I can see the UI of Fragment A, but can't interract with it. The application simply becomes unresponsive to any touch events and needs to be killed.

I added some logging and can see the following:

```
// app start
[main] INFO   MainActivity onStart
[main] INFO   MainActivity onResume
[main] INFO   FragmentA onResume
// system dialog shown
[main] INFO   MainActivity onPause
[main] INFO   FragmentA onPause
// replace fragment
[main] INFO   navigateTo(); fragmentName: FragmentB
[main] INFO   FragmentA onStop
[main] INFO   FragmentB onViewCreated
[main] INFO   FragmentB onStart
// dismiss system dialog
[main] INFO   MainActivity onResume
[main] INFO   FragmentB onResume
```

It looks like the issue might be related to the fact that the navigation happens when the app is "paused".

In addition, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53104873/2463035) which describes very similar (probably same) issue, and it suggests that the issue might be related to animation on Fragment transaction.

Edit:

After performing several more tests, it looks like this bug is indeed related to animated FragmentTransaction because I couldn't reproduce it if I remove the animation.

Edit 2:

Forgot to mention that this app hasn't been migrated to AndroidX yet, so it usses support Fragments:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

Edit 3:

I tried to build a minimal standalone app to reproduce this issue. While it reproduces quite easily inside the production app, I couldn't reproduce it in this standalone repo. Tried to add variable amounts of delays inside lifecycle methods, but it didn't help. Now I start to think that it might also be realated to some other feature as well...

I have several ideas about workarounds that I can use to fix this bug, but I'm really curious to know the root cause of this behavior and whether it's a bug in the application, or in Android framework.

Comment: The code you pasted is all needed to reproduce the error ?

Comment: @RamiLoiferman the app is quite big and messy, so I can't post all the code from it. However, as far as I can see right now, this behavior is unrelated to anything else.

Comment: I would need an isolated repro case for this one unfortunately, as I can't seem to reproduce it myself.

Comment: Try adding your fragment to back stack instead of replacing it.
using ```fragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, null)
        .commit();```

Comment: The fragment transaction occurs while the activity is paused, I suspect the issue can come from there. If you prevent this may be it works?